# how get current CPU temperature programmatically in all Android Versions?

Tags: java, android, cpu, temp

I am using this code for get current CPU Temperature :

and saw [it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51948718/how-to-get-android-cpu-temperature-programmatically) too

```
 private float getCurrentCPUTemperature() {
    String file = readFile("/sys/devices/virtual/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp", '\n');
    if (file != null) {
      return Long.parseLong(file);
    } else {
      return Long.parseLong(batteryTemp + " " + (char) 0x00B0 + "C");

    }
  }


private byte[] mBuffer = new byte[4096];

  @SuppressLint("NewApi")
  private String readFile(String file, char endChar) {
    // Permit disk reads here, as /proc/meminfo isn't really "on
    // disk" and should be fast.  TODO: make BlockGuard ignore
    // /proc/ and /sys/ files perhaps?
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy savedPolicy = StrictMode.allowThreadDiskReads();
    FileInputStream is = null;
    try {
      is = new FileInputStream(file);
      int len = is.read(mBuffer);
      is.close();

      if (len > 0) {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
          if (mBuffer[i] == endChar) {
            break;
          }
        }
        return new String(mBuffer, 0, i);
      }
    } catch (java.io.FileNotFoundException e) {
    } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
    } finally {
      if (is != null) {
        try {
          is.close();
        } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
        }
      }
      StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(savedPolicy);
    }
    return null;
  }
```

and use it like it :

```
float cpu_temp = getCurrentCPUTemperature();
txtCpuTemp.setText(cpu_temp + " " + (char) 0x00B0 + "C");
```

it is work like a charm but for android M and under. For Android N and above (7,8,9) Do not Work and Show The Temp like this :

**57.0 in android 6 and under (6,5,4)**

**57000.0 in android 7 and above (7,8,9)**

I try this code too :

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
      txtCpuTemp.setText((cpu_temp / 1000) + " " + (char) 0x00B0 + "C");
    }
```

but do not work :(

How can I get the Temp in all android versions??

**UPDATE:**

I change The code like it and work on some devices 
Except Samsung:

```
float cpu_temp = getCurrentCPUTemperature();
    txtCpuTemp.setText(cpu_temp + " " + (char) 0x00B0 + "C");

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
      txtCpuTemp.setText(cpu_temp / 1000 + " " + (char) 0x00B0 + "C");
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Divide the value by `1000` on newer API:

```
float cpu_temp = getCurrentCPUTemperature();
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    cpu_temp = cpu_temp / 1000;
}
```

I'd just wonder where `batteryTemp` comes from and how it should be related to the `CPU`.

Comment: ```if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
      txtCpuTemp.setText(cpu_temp / 1000 + " " + (char) 0x00B0 + "C");
    }```  I tired it and work now . but under android 6 be ok or not ??

Comment: Nope for batteryTemp We use this code : ```private BroadcastReceiver broadcastreceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

      batteryTemp = (float) (intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_TEMPERATURE, 0)) / 10;

      txtBatteryTemp.setText(batteryTemp + " " + (char) 0x00B0 + "C");
    }
  };```

Comment: tnx I do it like it and be ok : ```float cpu_temp = getCurrentCPUTemperature();
    txtCpuTemp.setText(cpu_temp + " " + (char) 0x00B0 + "C");

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
      txtCpuTemp.setText(cpu_temp / 1000 + " " + (char) 0x00B0 + "C");
    }```

Comment: why it shouldn't be "ok"? see [thermal/thermal.c](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/hardware/libhardware/+/master/modules/thermal/thermal.c)... multi-core CPU have multiple thermal zones. one can also read temperature from power-management ICs, eMMC and a few other circuits.