# How to get current Thermal values in Android Programatically?

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

[image: Thermal values through adb]

I am trying to get thermal values of my device programatically. I am able to do it in adb but unable to do this programatically. How can I loop over each and every directory in the directory "thermal" to get the particular value. Some part of my code is as following :

```
Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cd sys/class/thermal/");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I found to do this programatically. I used ***for*** loop to find the values. Visit the detailed answer [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64600415/13476891)

```
    for(int i=0;i<29;i++){
            float temp;
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cat sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone" + i + "/temp");
            process.waitFor();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
            String line = reader.readLine();
            if (line != null) {
                temp = Float.parseFloat(line);
            }
            reader.close();
            process.destroy();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access `/sys/class/thermal/` through an app because the user performing the action (something like `u0_aXYZ`) does not have enough permission to perform this action compared to a (root) `adb shell`.

You can do for instance:

```
adb shell
run-as your-app-package-name
```

and from now on you can navigate across the device file system and take a look at the folders your app can access.

If you want to proceed with that your only option is to have a rooted device and build an app with root permissions.

Comment: But after doing that how will I access those thermal values. There are many apps that do the same thing. Is there any other way around ?

Comment: please provide some links to these apps so that we can take a look, thanks!

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cpuid.cpu_z. Have a look at this one.