# Temperature monitoring of device for app usage in android

Tags: android

I am developing an android app which frequently communicates with server for downloading and uploading data.
Now I want to monitor the temperature of device in order to ascertain whether my app causes device to heat up or not.
Additionally I have tried using task managers but they don't give exact temperature range during the app usage.

Answer (score 0):

try to use Intents, with components like described there: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/BatteryManager.html#EXTRA_TEMPERATURE

Comment: Is battery temperature same as CPU temperature?

Comment: Of course not, I though you want to have battery temperature. Here are examples showing how to monitor CPU temp https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51948718/how-to-get-android-cpu-temperature-programmatically. It's worth mentoning that android studio has its own CPU inspector: https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/cpu-profiler